# How to handle multiple events at once, where one rules over the other

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to handle multiple states of a Counter-Strike events. I basically need to overrule some of the rules. Here are some examples of functions that could be triggered:

- If I shoot someone
- If I shoot someone, but I win the round, the `round won` should overrule my `shot someone`
- If I shoot someone in the head, it should overrule `shot someone`, but `round won` should overrule `headshot`

Other than that, I need to be able to cancel some events that are occuring at the moment. Basically say `STOP EVERYTHING AND DO THIS INSTEAD`. Let's imagine the code is hosted on my Raspberry Pi and I can control LEDs using my NodeJS code (basically what I am doing). I need to be able to stop current events, so the LED doesn't keep blinking a color, if something else happens instead. Here is a mockup of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var t_won = false;
var ct_won = false;
var bomb_planted = false;
var kills = 0;

server.on("update", function(data) {
    if(data.round.win_team == "T" && t_won == false) {
        t_won = true;
        blinkLED("red", 5);
    } else if(data.round.win_team == "CT" && ct_won == false) {
        ct_won = true;
        blinkLED("blue", 5);
    } else if(data.round.bomb == "planted" && bomb_planted == false) {
        bomb_planted = true;
        blinkLED("red", 40);
    } else if(data.round.bomb == "defused" && bomb_planted == true) {
        LED.stop();
        //ct_won(); or whatever
    }
});

function blinkLED(color, time) {
    //time = time in seconds
    LED.blink(color, time);
}
```

Does that make sense? It's basically pseudo code, but it works the same way. If the LED is blinking for 40 seconds (because the bomb has been planted), I need to be able to stop it, so I can trigger `ct_won` instead. I don't want to make all these variables hardcoded into the app, because that seems very bad.

Many of these can appear at the same time. The `data.round.bomb == "defused"` and `data.round.win_team == "CT"` are basically both true at the same time, so a big if-else-if chunk of code doesn't seem very wise now that I think about it.

Is something like this possible? It would be fine to have some kind of order system, so I can give the most important one `order: 1`, the second most important one `order: 2` and so on.

Comment: You can look at things like finite state machine libraries although for a limited number of states, explicitly handling the conditions is not really all that terrible. Or you can just use the finite state machine idea to roll yuour own. take a look at https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine

Comment: @pvg Thanks for the comment. That's very interesting. It's basically like saying "`this` overrules `that`" and "`this` overrules `this2` and `that`"?

Comment: well. I don't really know exactly what you mean by 'overrules' but what you're describing sounds an awful lot like a state machine so you should read up on that and see if you can codify what you want in those terms and then ask about specifics. As it is, your question sits somewhere in the uncanny valley between 'too broad', 'unclear what you're asking' and 'primarily opinion based.

Comment: @pvg What I'm really trying to say is: If the bomb has been planted, the state basically says the bomb has been planted. It should not blink the LED if I shoot someone or do anything else. If the bomb has been planted, nothing else is allowed to make the LED blink, unless it gets defused or someone wins the round (meaning the bomb is not planted anymore).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are thinking about implementing a rules engine like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-rules-engine.  This would be fun to play with, but from your example I do not believe it would be beneficial.  Best would be to just try to simplify your code a bit if possible and stick with plain JavaScript code.

If you notice I have done a few things to clean up the ifs. One is to separate detecting new state, another using the same property names, also breaking winner and bomb indications into their own function, also getting led color from team object, and return instead of else if.  This is is equivalent to the ifs but more readable.

```
let state = { won: null, bomb: null };
let team = { terrorist: 'red', counterTerrorist: 'blue' }

function detectNewState(data) {
  let newState = {};
  for (key in state)
    if (state[key] != data[key]) {
      newState[key] = data[key];
      state[key] = data[key];
    }
  return newState;      
}

function indicateWinner(won) {
  blinkLED(team[won], 5);
}

function indicateBomb(bomb) {
  blinkLed(team[bomb], 40);
}

function update(data) {
  const {won, bomb} = detectNewState(data);
  if (won) return indicateWinner(won);
  if (bomb) return indicateBomb(bomb);
});

server.on('update', update);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah I do believe vanilla JavaScript would be a good way to do this. My friend suggested I could simply keep the state in a variable, and have a whole lot of it-statements in the right order. The one with highest priority gets put at the bottom, then it just gets overwritten. `if(state == "ct_won") { blinkLED("blue", 5) }` underneath all the if-statements.

Comment: Ok please see the edits I added explaining how mine is equivalent to the ifs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How does something like this work? Let's assume the bomb has been planted and it has priority number 1. This means that nothing can interrupt the bomb function from triggering. If you kill someone: Too bad. Also, you need to imaging that `server.on("update", update)` happens many, many times per second. The JSON, [as you can see an "example" of here](https://pastebin.com/FLATE957), gets sent many times per second and contains all the game's states. Two or more states can be true at the same time (like bomb planted and I kill someone).

Comment: ok, if the condition matches then it returns and doesn't look at the other conditions.  Your LED is not going to be able to indicate infinite things.. people will forget what the purple light means.  You'll need to add logic to make sure the indication does not change too fast since there are many updates per second.

Comment: That makes sense yeah. How do I trigger this though? I can't seem to figure it out. If I set a state like `"bomb": "planted"` and I do `update(state.bomb)`, what then?

Comment: With my code you call update with the complete state not just one property, since thats how you described it at first.

Comment: I don't see how I am supposed to do that though. `let state = { won: null, bomb: "planted" }` If I then do `update(state)`, it should return the `bomb: "planted"` or so, right? I really need more information regarding how this is set up and how it works, because it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: detectNewState returns whats changed, yes.  It was just to try to give you ideas about how to decompose those if statements.  Maybe try running the code, or if it doesn't seem clearer that way then just put everything in if statements.  I cant explain more clearly than that code.

Comment: Look up destructuring javascript if not familiar with that